# How to set  Jumbo Packet and Receive/Transmit Buffers for advanced network adapter properties in Windows?

Tags: c#, c++, network-programming, wmi

I am trying to set some advanced properties for Network adapter e.g. Jumbo Packet, Receive/Transmit Buffers. I tried with Win32_NetworkAdapter, Win32_NetworkConnection, Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WMI classes. None of them can do that.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

"Jumbo Packet" support just means a big MTU (typically 9000 bytes).  Maybe the [SetMTU method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class, or the [SetIFEntry()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (see the [dwMtu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) field).

The size of the transmit and receive buffers is set at the socket level, independent of the network interface.  Look for an interface to [setsockopt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF` options.

Comment: The SetMTU method of the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class is no longer supported. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. The GetIFEntry returns 14 bytes fewer than what is currently set. The size of the transmit and receive buffers is can also be set for each network adapter. In Windows 7 go to "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" -> Right click -> Select Properties -> Configure -> Advanced Tab.

Comment: What about the suggested `SetIFEntry`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at the .Net APIs.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ew4thdx.aspx

Comment: System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace has no classes to set these properties