# Is there a way to configure receive/transmit buffer sizes for a network card via C#

Tags: c#, networking, windows-10, network-interface

I'm currently working on a networked application for a Windows 10 PC. The PC must have 1 network adapter that is configured to use the maximum receive buffers, transmit buffers, and jumbo frames.

I've looked at the Socket classes, and there is indeed a receive/transmit buffer, but this doesn't appear to be what I'm looking for. I'm looking to replicate the functionality in C# that is performed when adapter options are modified via Windows adapter options UI, i.e. the network interface, not a socket using that interface.

So far I've been able to do a not-perfect read of jumbo frames via IPv4InterfaceProperties.Mtu, but I've been unable to find reliable information for setting jumbo frames, or reading/setting the receive/transmit buffer size.

I have looked on SO, but many answers either use methods that are no longer supported or don't work on different PCs.

Is there any way I can reliably read these properties on multiple PCs via C# (.NET Framework 4.6.1), and set them too? Any helpful pointers are welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set  Jumbo Packet and Receive/Transmit Buffers for advanced network adapter properties in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192751/how-to-set-jumbo-packet-and-receive-transmit-buffers-for-advanced-network-adapt)

Comment: I'd read that post previously. The first answer suggests SetMTU (not supported) or SetIFEntry. The links appear to use C++ as well. I'd prefer a C# solution, but in the mean time I can look into calling SetIFEntry from C#. The second answer suggests Network Information in C#, but it doesn't appear to support the functionality I need (although I may just suck at navigating MSDN).